# Javascript onscroll simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am kinda new with javascript and i am trying to make div id="foo" trigger when i scroll over div id="container", in order to say "IM AWESOME" when i scroll through the id "container". I even gave quite enough space to make sure i can scroll with all the `<br>` or by adding margin-top and bottom but still not working properly. If you guys could help me that would be awesome. 
"im aware that i shouldnt use so many "breaklines" but its just a draft code".

```js
var x = document.getElementById('container');
  x.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "IM AWESOME";

}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <br>
     <div id="container">
         
        </div>
    
     <div id="foo">do something</div>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how, but  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_svg_scrolldrawing) may come in handy.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery method. You have to calculate the offset of that ID and if the ID of that container is less than $(window).scrollTop() then execute your cute.

Example:

```
var $container = ('.container'),
    $window = $(window).scrollTop(),

yourfunction = function(){
if($container < $window){
//run your code
}
});

$(window).on('scroll', yourfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height and width for the container and then scrolling inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.pageYOffset` to get the **current scrolling position** and compare it with the distance of the element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

```
function testScroll(ev){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= document.getElementById("foo").offsetTop){
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "IM AWESOME";
    }
}
window.onscroll=testScroll
```

[Full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/kpqwxaym/)